# MVC non constant for attribute argument to sync with Membership properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, membership-provider

First off, I'm fairly new to MVC but have an existing project in MVC3 and playing around with MVC4 so answers for both versions are appreciated.

In my mvc View I have this line:

```
Passwords must be at least @Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength characters long.
```

and in the Model I have this:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

(These were auto generated for an MVC template project)

My web.config MembershipProvider has this attribute:

```
minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
```

The problem with this is that the user will be informed that the min length is 8 but the actual validation will be 6.
Naturally, I can set both to the same value but I wanted to know if there is an easy way to only make use of one of them or syncing both.

I've tried this:

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength)]
```

but get the error 'An attribute argument must be a constant expression,...'

I am aware of the option of writing custom validation attributes but I would like to avoid this because I would essentially be writing validation logic that already exists (with the exception of the source of the values)

Alternatively, can I display what the MinimumLenght of the model is in the view?

How can I have only one place to make a change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a more straightforward way (since it must be a constant value), however [you could write your own CustomValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and check the web.config value in there.

Comment: Yes, I did come across that option, but I would be writing custom validators that achieve the same validation logic already existing (with the exception of the source of the values). I would prefer avoiding this if possible but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Your answer may not be what I was hoping for but it seems to be what I would need to do, so I've marked it as the answer. I would give you a +1 on the rating but I don't have the required 15 points yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good way but here is what I did...

Put this into MembershipHelper.cs:

```
namespace System.Web.Security
{
    public static class MembershipHelper
    {
        public const int MinRequiredPasswordLength = 6;// Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength is defined in Web.Config
        public const int MaxRequiredPasswordLength = 30;
    }
}
```

Then in views you can do this:

```
<p>
    Passwords must be at least @MembershipHelper.MinRequiredPasswordLength characters long. 
</p>
```

In models you can do this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is required.")]
[StringLength(MembershipHelper.MaxRequiredPasswordLength, ErrorMessage = "Must be between {2} and {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = MembershipHelper.MinRequiredPasswordLength )]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

I will still have to change it in two places but that is better than 3 or more.

If anyone sees any issues with this please let me know.